# how to display javascript object property correctly in HTML-page of website

Tags: javascript, html, object

I managed to get a certain PHP variable ($length) that contains the length of a message (stored in a MYSQL-database) to get passed to a javascript variable (var = length) in order to let javascript decide whether or not to show a certain marquee on a HTML-page. The present javascript code (with a lot of thanks to Mr. Polywhirl) which in basic is working, uses the document.write statement to get the output displayed. However, using document-write "kills" my present HTML-page. So I tried to find an alternative, by defining an extra function, using innerHTML. But yet I can't get this code to work ...

The initial javascipt code that is working correctly, but it "kills" my HTML-page, is the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var length = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.transitum.org/linski_nach/check3.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { length: length },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data); // 53
      if (textStatus === "success" && jqXHR.readyState === 4) {
        length = JSON.parse(data); // Set the global variable
        if(length <1)
        {
            document.write(length);            
            document.write("<table><td>no message available</td></table>");
        }
        else
        {
            document.write(length);
            document.write('<iframe src="https://www.transitum.org/linski_nach/test3.php" width="100%" height="55" border="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
        }
        } else {
        // Do nothing...
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

So I have made some changes to get the output correctly displayed within my HTML-page and leaving this HTML-page intact, instead of "replacing" my HTML-page completely. This code is the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var length = 0;
var message = 0

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.transitum.org/linski_nach/check3.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { length: length },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data); // 53
      if (textStatus === "success" && jqXHR.readyState === 4) {
        length = JSON.parse(data); // Set the global variable
        if(length <1)
        { var message = { item:"<iframe src='https://www.bruedergrimmschule.de/linski_nach/test3.php' width='100%' height='55' </iframe>" };
        }
        else
        { var message = { item:"<table><td>no message available</td></table>" };
        }
        } else {
        // Do nothing...
      }
    }
  });
});

function displayDetails() {
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = this.item;
}
message.showDetails = displayDetails;
message.showDetails();

</script>

<div id="details"></div>
```

This time the HTML-page itself is fully and correctly displayed, but there is no output at all from the javascript-code to be seen.

How to solve?

Comment: There are 2 variables called `message`. message variable which has declared inside the if-condition is not referring to the global variable. set values without var keyword. like `message = { item:"<table><td>no message available</td></table>" };`

Comment: Change `div` or variable `message` after getting the succes request. Inside `success` setting

Comment: I have changed "var message" to "message" so, now that part of the code is:
~~~~
 if(length <1)
        { message = { item:"<iframe src='https://www.bruedergrimmschule.de/linski_nach/test3.php' width='100%' height='55' </iframe>" };
        }
        else
        { message = { item:"<table><td>no message available</td></table>" };
        }
~~~~
But that doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put variable `message` changing into `success` property of `$.ajax` method and remove `var message` declaration inside `if` condition

```
var length = 0;
var message = 0
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    // type: "POST",
        type: "GET",
    // url: "https://www.transitum.org/linski_nach/check3.php",
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ta9cn",
    // dataType: "json",
    data: { length: length },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data); // 53
      if (textStatus === "success" && jqXHR.readyState === 4) {
        length = JSON.parse(data); // Set the global variable
        if (length < 1) { 
                    message = { item:"<iframe src='https://www.bruedergrimmschule.de/linski_nach/test3.php' width='100%' height='55' </iframe>" };
        } else { 
                    message = { item:"<table><td>no message available</td></table>" };
        }
                message.showDetails = displayDetails;
                message.showDetails();
      } else {
        // Do nothing...
      }
    }
  });
    function displayDetails() {
        document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = this.item;
    }

});
```

In this example I've changed url to check code functionality.
You can see the example here: https://codepen.io/dsb/pen/NWKjowO

Comment: I tried your script-proposal. In the backend it works. However, looking at the URL directly, nothing gets shown, probably due to timing issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad practice to use global variables and even more in javascript, given that it is asynchronous. So, given,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.transitum.org/linski_nach/check3.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { length: length },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      // ...
    }
});
```

and

```
function displayDetails() {
    document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = this.item;
}
message.showDetails = displayDetails;
message.showDetails();
```

JS engine will trigger the AJAX call but at the same time will execute in a new thread the second block of code, causing that effect of code not seen, because at the time `showDetails()` is called, variable `item` is probably undefined (because the AJAX call is slower or has not finished)

A workaround for your code would be to execute the change directly inside the `if` block. But take into account to create first the HTML element. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="details">

        </div>

        <!-- JS code -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="..."/>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my JS code would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.transitum.org/linski_nach/check3.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { length: length },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (textStatus === "success" && jqXHR.readyState === 4) {
             length = JSON.parse(data);
             $("#details").html("<iframe src='https://www.bruedergrimmschule.de/linski_nach/test3.php' width='100%' height='55' </iframe>")
          } else {
             $("#details").html("<table><td>no message available</td></table>")
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you encounter any issue.

PD: I strongly recommend that you use a proper framework such as Angular and use good practices such as subscribers. The learning curve is somewhat complicated, but you will catch the idea of it quickly. There's a great and large community out there!

Comment: I tried your script-proposal. In the backend it works. However, looking at the URL directly, nothing gets shown, probably due to timing issues.

Comment: Please let me know by using the Chrome Dev Tools what is the issue back-end is supposedly giving you. It is normally a 408-http error code. If so, it has generally to do with your server not the front-end code (unless thousands of requests are sent and server collapses).

Comment: with google-chrome browser I had a look at https://www.transitum.org/try_7/ (where the script is deployed) and marked the word "empty". After that I did a right mouse click and did an "inspect" on the empty-element. This did not yet give me a clear indication of what is going wrong ...